# Using "nameof" operator in Razor views

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, c#-6.0

On my VS.NET 2015 development machine, the Razor views that use the [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) work like a charm.

When deploying to a Windows server, it fails to compile the CSHTML Razor views:

> The name 'nameof' does not exist in the current context.

In German:

> Der Name 'nameof' ist im aktuellen Kontext nicht vorhanden.

I've installed .NET Framework 4.6 ("ASP.NET version: 4.6.81.0") with no success.

Most likely I'm missing something plain simple.

Still, I'm really clueless. Is it a web.config setting? Or something else?

**My question:**

How to enable C# 6 features (like the `nameof` operator) in CSHTML Razor views?

Comment: Thanks, @Ksv3n I've did it (again), just to be sure. No change in results, still the compilation error. "`Versionsinformationen: Microsoft .NET Framework-Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET-Version:4.6.81.0`"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Make sure in your file "web.config" the node `system.codedom` exists.

```xml
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
 </system.codedom>
```

And you'd reference the package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`.

Comment: That actually did the trick. Those lines were present on my local dev machine but not on the server. Thank you!

Comment: does this go in the main `Web.config` or Views' `Web.config`?

Comment: @Maslow main Web.config

Answer (score 37):

According to [this site](http://dusted.codes/using-csharp-6-features-in-aspdotnet-mvc-5-razor-views), you need to reference the Roslyn compiler in your Web.config file to get C# 6 features to work in your razor views.

This can be achieved simply by installing the [CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/).

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
```

Comment: This answer overwrites the [chsword] one's.

Comment: I also had to restart Visual Studio (2015)

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you! Also, second for restart of VS.