# Define HTML attribute name with razor syntax

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

With `MVC 5` and `Razor 3` I'm trying to dynamically create an `HTML` Attribute Name with razor syntax, specifically a `data-*` attribute.

So this is about the ***name*** of the attribute and *not* the *value*.

### Example for terminology:

`<div data-foo="bar">`

Attribute **Name**: `data-foo`
Attribute Value: `bar`

This is what I'm trying with Razor syntax:

```
<div data-search-@Model.Name="@view.Name">
<div data-search-@(Model.Name)="@view.Name">
```

Neither examples are recognized by Razor and are rendered *as is*. So the `html` attribute name output is literally: `data-search-@Model.Name`.

Razor:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Am I out of luck here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "nameof" operator in Razor views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822854/using-nameof-operator-in-razor-views)

Comment: @PeterB Nope, that's not a duplicate, since `nameof()` *does* work, because I have the roslyn compiler configured for my project. But for clarity's sake I'll edit my answer just to prove the point that razor syntax simply is not recognized inside an html attribute name.

Comment: Please add what you get for that snippet in the browser -> view source ? Or an error?

Comment: @PeterB edited my question for you again. There is no error, the output is *as is*.

Comment: I can't test it myself right now. Perhaps the rewrite of cshtml to cs (done by the Razor engine) is throwing things off. There are ways to see what it generates, perhaps that could help to explain it: https://coding.abel.nu/2013/08/examining-the-generated-cs-file-for-a-cshtml-view/ (also, the `nameof` is now missing after `data-search-` in your question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128255/discussion-between-quantumhive-and-peter-b).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the reason it doesn't work is, that `@` is actually a [valid character for an attribute in HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#attributes-2), and therefore Razor will not activate "code-mode" in this exact scenario. You could achieve what you are trying to do by building the attribute name completely in Razor code as follows:

```
<div @("data-search-" + Model.Name)="@view.Name">
```

However, this is not particularly pretty and although it functions properly, it can cause Visual Studio and ReSharper to complain about a missing attribute name. Instead I would probably make a helper function:

```
public class HtmlAttribute : IHtmlString
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    public HtmlAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string ToHtmlString()
    {
        return $"{Name}=\"{Value}\"";
    }
}

public class static HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static HtmlAttribute Attribute(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, string value)
    {
        return new HtmlAttribute(name, value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div @Html.Attribute("data-search-" + Model.Name, view.Name)></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version for ASP.NET Core

```
public class HtmlAttribute : IHtmlContent
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Value { get; }

    public HtmlAttribute(string name, string value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }

    public void WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HtmlEncoder encoder)
    {
        writer.Write($"{Name}=\"{Value}\"");
    }
}

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static HtmlAttribute Attribute(this IHtmlHelper helper, string name, string value)
    {
        return new HtmlAttribute(name, value);
    }
}
```